# How to pull git repository on Linux Startup

Tags: systemd, kali-linux, git, startup, github

I want a Kali Linux 2021 (with zsh) machine in a lab to pull the most recent copy of a git repository on startup.  I can get the commands to run fine manually, but for the life of me I cannot get them to run on startup.  The repository is a public one that doesn't require login, and below are the commands I'm running, which discard any changes and grab the most recent files:

```
/usr/bin/git -C /home/user/localrepo reset --hard main
/usr/bin/git -C /home/user/localrepo pull
```

I've tried adding these commands to `.profile`, `.bash_login`, created a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/script.sh` and `/etc/profile.d/`, running on reboot from crontab, and I've lost track of the other ways.  I really have no idea why it's not working on startup.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[EDIT] I will add that this was running in a virtual lab environment which had a gateway that loaded about 45 seconds after the Kali VM came up, so that was one issue I had to get around.  That may have been why the script didn't appear to run.  To address the comments, no, I didn't receive any errors and I checked the supposed git logs and didn't see anything there either.

Comment: kali uses systemd, correct? if so, you should just run a sh script as a service on boot with default.target. plenty of examples floating around with example .service files.

Comment: Thank you and yeah, it does run systemd.  So the solution ended up being a lot simpler.  I ended up using the LightDM desktop manager's startup application tool to set my script to startup on login, which did exactly what I wanted.  I later found that some desktop managers simply ignore the usual startup scripts as well, but will read ~/.xprofile.  By this point though, I had a working solution and had spent way too much time already so I didn't bother to check.

Comment: It's not clear what happened when you tried.

Comment: I get your point, I guess I can say the git clone didn't happen.  I was having a hard time determining if the script ran or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could use systemd to do that task:

```
# $HOME/.config/systemd/user/gitpull.service
[Unit]
Description=Pulling recent git repo

[Unit]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/git -C %h/localrepo reset --hard main
ExecStart=/usr/bin/git -C %h/localrepo pull

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then to test it:

```
$ systemctl --user start gitpull
```

If you're happy, then enable it to run on login with:

```
$ systemctl --user enable gitpull
```

Notes:

- This uses the `--user` bus instead of the default `--system` bus. That's because you want this to run when your user logs in, not when the machine boots.  You also want the files to be owned by the user (not `root`).  Don't run those `systemctl` commands as root.
- If you did want to run this on the `--system` bus, then you'd want to add `User=` to the `[Unit]` section.
- You'll see that the service is `activating` during the operation, and then `dead` when it is complete.  That's the nature of `Type=oneshot` so don't panic when you see `dead`.
- `WantedBy=default.target` means this script will run, even if your "log-in" is from a TTY or ssh.  LightDM will trigger this, but other things can too.  If you ONLY want a graphical login to trigger this, use `WantedBy=graphical-session.target`.
- `%h` is short for your user's home directory.
- You could replace `-C %h/localrepo` with `WorkingDirectory=%h/localrepo`

Comment: This is a good solution but wouldn't work in my case since I had to wait for an upstream gateway in the virtual environment to come up.

Comment: @hypercoyote `systemd` would work fine for this, just create a second service that this service depends on. That service would fail by design and systemd would restart it over time until it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using LightDM's Session and Startup tool from the LightDM GUI to set my script to start on login and it worked fine.  The script didn't run until the user logged in, which was exactly what I wanted.  I'm still not sure why it wouldn't work from the normal file locations, but I suspect LightDM/Zsh were to blame for that.

[EDIT] One major issue ended up being that the script was running before the virtual environment's gateway had come up.  I created a wrapper script to check for this before running my other script to pull from GitHub.  I could've put them in the same script, but I preferred to use a wrapper.

```
#/home/kali/bin/git-check.sh "<cmd to run>"
#!/bin/bash
# Give networking a chance to come up
printf "Waiting for Internet connectivity\n"
RESPONSE=0
while [ $RESPONSE != 2 ] && [ $RESPONSE != 3 ]
do
        RESPONSE=$(curl -s --max-time 2 -I http://github.com | sed 's/^[^ ]*  *\([0-9]\).*/\1/; 1q')
        case $RESPONSE in
                [23]) printf "\nHTTP connectivity is up\n";;
                5) printf "\nAccess denied or server error\n";;
                *) printf "\nThe network is down or very slown\n";;
        esac
done
$1
```

Comment: Well, you'd have to debug to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I did a strace on the system and it is actually loading the expected files.  Mine loaded these (or tried to):

~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
~/.bashrc

So that makes even less sense why this wasn't working.  But yeah, the Session & Startup tool does the job.  As much as I'm curious why, I have to work on other stuff.

Comment: I should have elaborated on the environment but I didn't realize it was relevant.  This is a pod in an online student lab and the pod has a firewall that comes online with the pod.  One issue I was having that I didn't realize was the firewall was still coming up by the time the script ran, so of course I couldn't do the git pull.  I added a curl command to check connectivity before running the command to fix that.  I found that idea here:  https://itectec.com/unixlinux/shell-scripting-proper-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity/

Comment: Still form your question it was not clear that the command would run, but output an error message; at least that its what I'd expect from your comment. The question sounds as if the command wasn't started. That's quite a different thing.

Comment: I'll modify it with what I know now, but at the time, I wasn't getting an error and it didn't appear the command was running.  So my question was an accurate reflection of the knowledge I had at the time I posted it.